# CKEditor Blazor integration

Tags: html, file-upload, ckeditor, blazor

I am trying to use CKeditor with Blazor.
I used Online builder to create a custom build, with ImageUpload and Base64UploadAdapter, and it is integrated in BlazorApp.

I can successfully show it on the page, and put / get HTML content from it.
Source of the working version for Blazor app is here https://gitlab.com/dn-misc/BlazorCKEditor1/

But as I would like to inser image as Base64 encoded string directly in HTML content, when I try to upload image I get following error:
Assertion Failed: Input argument is not an HTMLInputElement (from content-script.js)

Comment: Hi Dino I was just looking at your source. I cant see anything wrong except I cannot verify your scripts. Where is Index.html?? I have almost identical source here working.

Comment: This is Blazor, so index.html page is generated from /pages/Index.razor. Layout of the site is created from /shared/MainLayout.razor
CKEditor scripts are in /wwwroot/ckeditor/

Comment: Index html loads the app and the scripts needed for the app. Usually there is a Index.html in he www folder. The app then loads the route "/" which is normally defined in Index.razor by convention. I was looking for :

    <script src="js/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CKEditorInterop.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

Comment: This repo has the base 64 image option https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorCkEditor5 . It is in preview 8 though.

Comment: All the scripts includes are in /Pages/_Host.cshtml.

Comment: All the scripts includes are in /Pages/_Host.cshtml.
CKeditor included scripts were created with CKEditor5 online builder (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) so ImageUpload and Base64Upload are included in this build. I added full build to /wwwroot/ckeditor there is ckeditor.zip file

Answer (score 6):

I have successfully implemented [Chris Pratt](https://cpratt.co/blazor-rich-text-editor-using-ckeditor/) implementation. Check this out:

**IMPORTANT: this works with ClassicEditor ONLY.**

Blazor component, I called mine **InputCKEditor.razor**. Yeah I know, no very original.

```
@namespace SmartApp.Components

@inherits InputTextArea
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<textarea @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
          id="@Id"
          class="@CssClass"
          value="@CurrentValue"></textarea>

@code {
    string _id;
    [Parameter]
    public string Id
    {
        get => _id ?? $"CKEditor_{_uid}";
        set => _id = value;
    }

    readonly string _uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower().Replace("-", "");

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CKEditorInterop.init", Id, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public Task EditorDataChanged(string data)
    {
        CurrentValue = data;
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CKEditorInterop.destroy", Id);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Then, you have to put this in your **interop.js**

```
CKEditorInterop = (() => {
    var editors = {};

    return {
        init(id, dotNetReference) {
            window.ClassicEditor
                .create(document.getElementById(id))
                .then(editor => {
                    editors[id] = editor;
                    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                        var data = editor.getData();

                        var el = document.createElement('div');
                        el.innerHTML = data;
                        if (el.innerText.trim() === '')
                            data = null;

                        dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('EditorDataChanged', data);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        },
        destroy(id) {
            editors[id].destroy()
                .then(() => delete editors[id])
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    };
})();
```

Now time to use it:

```
<form>
    <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label text-sm-left text-lg-right">Description</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-6">
        <InputCKEditor @bind-Value="_model.Description" class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg"></InputCKEditor>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.Description)" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The above code results in runtime error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Blog.Web.Pages.Article.<BuildRenderTree>b__9_0(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)

Comment: Because we are binding the input, you need to wrap InputCKEditor with the Blazor <EditForm></EditForm>. Good luck.

Comment: Where did you inject interop.js ? did you add css and js files of ckeditor in Index.html?

Comment: That's correct, I'm using Blazor Wasm.

Comment: @JavierContreras - have you tried it with the new Blazor SSR setup?

Comment: @MarshallPenn, I haven't tested it with SSR. Are you facing any issue?

Comment: @JavierContreras - yes there is an issue - when you navigate back to the page with the RTE on it, it does not show. Its okay the first time

Answer (score 0):

I had a small issue with the code written by @Javier.

In my code I was passing in a configuration parameter (as well as the `dotNetReference`) so we could change the look and feel of the CKEditor for different pages based on a config script. The `dotNetReference` variable was always 'undefined' when initializing the CKEditor.

So in the `InputCKEditor.razor` when calling the `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CKEditorInterop.init", Id, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));` I instanciated `DotNetObjectReference.Create(this)` into a variable first. This then had an instanciated object when the javascript was run.

The .js code (NOTE: the additional `configFunction` parameter)

```
CKEditorInterop = (() => {
      return {
        init(id, configFunction, dotNetReference) {
          CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
            extraAllowedContent: 'b i div class strong table th tr td label div class [*] {*}',
          });
          for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function () {
              var data = CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData();
              var el = document.createElement('div');
              el.innerHTML = data;
              if (el.innerText.trim() === '')
                data = null;
    
              dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('EditorDataChanged', data);
            });
          }
    
          if (configFunction !== undefined && configFunction !== 'null') {
            var fn = window[configFunction];
            fn(id);
          }      
        },
        destroy(id) {
          CKEDITOR.instances[id].desctoy();
        }
      };
    })();
```

The C# code:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender) {
    var obj = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this); // *** Instanciated here and this populated the object passed into the javascript ***
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CKEditorInterop.init", Id, obj);
  }

  await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

Im unsure why I needed to do this but it solved my issue.